# How to add three legends of a bar graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, legend, precision-recall

i have a bar graph which calculates precession and recall for three different methods and represents them in three different colors, code i used is as follows

```
x=[0.4,0.31,0.21]
y=[0.45,0.38,0.27]
bar(x,y,0.1)
h = bar(x,diag(y),0.1,'stacked');
xlabel('precession')
ylabel('recall')
```

[image]

i want to add a legend that should show `maroon color is for indiscernible relation`, `green is for discernible relation` and `blue is for equivalence relation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
legend('indiscernible relation','cernible relation' ,'equivalence relation')
```

Colors will be automatically inserted to the legend